# Where can I ask about help with personal doubts I am having?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want some advice about personal doubts I am having, and would like to know if there is any site on Stack Exchange network where I might ask for such advice?

Comment: There is https://health.stackexchange.com/ with the [mental-health tag](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health). It's bit far fetched, but the closest you will get in Stack Exchange, most likely.

Comment: I'm not sure if Stack Exchange can help you. I saw your post before it was deleted. I'm not a psychologist, but it seemed to me (as an outsider) that you might benefit from a trainer or coach - an expert who can give some personalized help, based on actually meeting you IRL. Either way, I'm sure that there other people who experience the same difficulties that you do. So, maybe you can find communities with them, and see what helped them. Good luck!

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Of note, the site has since changed its name to Medical Sciences and now bans subjective questions of the sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't have a site like this on the network. You are asking questions that are either very broad ("I really need help with learning things") or very subjective ("I really need some good practical advice"). Asking for recommendations for off-site resource ("I also want to know of some good website or a platform") is also not a good fit for this type of Q&A.

I would suggest to try another place on the web that is better suited to generalized discussion, like Quora. The type of questions you are trying to ask are not really a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Patrick, Sure. If you ask me for something and I respond, *"I don't do that; take your random question elsewhere..."*, do you hear the curt and dismissive tone? I know the author's question has been discussed a thousand times, but to anyone looking on, it sounded more annoyed than immediately necessary. Nothing egregious... I just softened it up a bit.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It came out different than I meant to @Rob

Comment: @RobertCartaino keep in mind the author of this question posted two other questions before this: first they just posted the actual full question right here in MSE (which was quickly closed and deleted), then they posted another question asking why the first got closed, and only then came this one which is finally legit. All of this can easily lead to antagonism.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [okay, as long as we're talking about this] Yes it's a common UX problem that falls (at least partially) on SE to fix. But the way we advise users in these misunderstandings doesn't just reach that one person; it's seen (potentially) by thousands. SE has a reputation of being unfriendly and insular, so unless an issue has escalated to obvious antagonism with bad actors, we need to talk to new users like they're seeing this for the first time. We're here to inform and teach [and I'm completely aware this goes way beyond the minor changes I thought this particular post warranted]

Comment: @Robert I was talking about human behavior actually (explaining the first version of this answer, and the amount of downvotes on this question now, which I don't think are deserved), not SE software, and I'm afraid you can't change/control human reactions to previous events. But if you have something in mind for SE that will somehow help, that would be welcome. :)